# Apache rule to redirect requests

Tags: php, apache

Is there a rule i can use to redirect requests to a different server using a proxy? Or maybe redirect the requests to one php file, and let it handle the remote proxy request using curl.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect is little more than a 3xx HTTP response code. How the client treats that response code is entirely up to the client. Particularly, there is no way to force the client to use a certain proxy.

Comment: But i could consievably redirect all requests to a file named "proxify.php" on the server, and then that file could use requests to gather the content from other locations on different servers and echo it. No?

Comment: How do i do that first redirect? :)
I want every request going to one php file.